# tabs with grids in an admin extension that is not a form

Tags: admin, extensions, grid, grid-serlization, tabs

I have been searching for an example of how to write an extension page with tabs and on each tab is a grid.  I don't need a form, just the mass action too.  Any one have a link to this?  What I'm doing is converting something I have which is under `/myext/mycontrol/index/` which I would like to keep and not end up with `/admin/mycontrol/index`.

An example would be ideal, but if someone can layout the files, for two tabs with grids and the classes, that would be enough I know it.  Here is what I have so far for the blocks and controllers.

```
+-Block
|+-Mycontrol.php
|+-Mycontrol
| |+-Tabs.php
| |+-Action1.php
| |+-Action1
|   |+-Grid.php
+-controllers
 |+-MycontrolController.php
```

I see the page but no tabs.  Here are the file stubs with out the method, as I'm sure that is the issue at hand here.

**admin\Mycomp\Myext\Block\Mycontrol.php**

```
<?php
class Mycomp_Myext_Block_Mycontrol extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'mycontrol';
        $this->_controller = 'media';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('myext')->__('Welcome');
        parent::__construct();
    }


}
```

**admin\Mycomp\Myext\Block\Mycontrol\Tabs.php**

```
<?php
class Mycomp_Myext_Block_Mycontrol_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('myext_tabs');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('myext')->__('media controll'));
    }
    protected function _beforeToHtml(){
        $activeSection = $this->_getActiveSection();
        //normal stuff
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    protected function _getActiveSection($default = 'orphaned'){
        //normal stuff
        return $activeSection;
    }
}
```

**admin\Mycomp\Myext\Block\Mycontrol\Action1.php**

```
class Mycomp_Myext_Block_Mycontrol_Action1 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->_controller = 'mycontrol_action1';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'mycomp_myext';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('myext')->__('Find Orphaned Images');
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }

    public function getCreateUrl() {
        return '';
    }

    public function getHeaderCssClass() {
        return '';
    }
}
```

**admin\Mycomp\Myext\Block\Mycontrol\Action1\Grid.php**

```
<?php

class Mycomp_Myext_Block_Mycontrol_Action1_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('mycontrol_action1Grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('prod_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    public function getId(){
        return 'myext_tabs_action1_section_content';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection(){
        //normal stuff
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns(){
        //normal stuff
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction(){
        //normal stuff
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Something tells me it's just in this order I'm messing up, but for the life of me I can't find one darn example that is not talking about adding tabs to the product page or tabs, edit, and forms.  Can some one lay it out?

**Update**
I have been trying different ways to make this happen.  Googling has not help.  I do recall some wiki that had an example of on the magento site but I can't find that either.  If anyone has the ability, a layout of the files needed and the classes is all I need.  A good point in the right direction.

As I understand, I should be close, and tried (I can't seem to find the reference now but something like) `$this->add_left()` but that was not working either.

Comment: have you looked for grid serialization ?

Comment: yes, not sure that was helping meet the condition I'm trying to hit here.  Got an example?  something you have/or knows works and produces what is described?  All I see with `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Serializer` examples I find is that I must do `GRID->FORM->TABS->EDIT` if that makes sense, but I want mass action on girds, and one grid on each tab, and not as forms, so I'm looking for something like `TABS->GRID`.  The only other thing I was trying to do was keep it under the custom path and not go to `/admin/*/*` I know I have seen extensions that do this, if I could only remember lol

Comment: May be refer this link http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/ hope you can get some idea

Comment: I have looked at that already.  Doesn't clear up the question.  It's a grid, to form with tab... I want tabs with a grid in them.

Comment: Have you tried Marius's Ultimate Module Creator? https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9

Comment: @B00MER yes I have taken a look at it to see if maybe I could set up a shell so I could see how it was done.  I was not able to get how to use the extension well enough to even produce tabs, and it was buggy as well as lacking in the needed instructions to get me where I needed.  If you know how to do it in there, I know the module can be save for download

Comment: I would love to know why this is a question worth downvoting, it's clear and it's relevant.

Comment: @jeremy.bass, Is it solved, I have same requirement for my custom module, If solved this then Help me. I have asked this question here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25846/magento-grid-with-tabs-not-in-edit-page-tabs-in-grid-page

Comment: @Charlie I have not yet solved this and will not be getting back around for a few more week on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't attached your layout xml file. If you have the correct layout set there, then you are almost there. But until you don't see any error messages in your log files your layout is not correctly set. Why to expect errors in the logs? When you want to show a tab and you implement the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`, you have to write the interface's methods: `getTabLabel`, `getTabTitle`, `canShowTab`, `isHidden`. I don't see these methods in your `Mycontrol.php` block. Also you must have a container for the tabs' content. Have a look at `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/catalog.xml` and see how it is implemented there the layout xml at node `adminhtml_catalog_product_new`. You will see there something like:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit" name="product_edit"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs" name="product_tabs"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_js" template="catalog/product/js.phtml" name="catalog_product_js"></block>
        <block type="core/template" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
```

What you are interested in is the `left` reference and the `content`. First, look at the `adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs` block class' constructor. You will see:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('product_info_tabs');
    $this->setDestElementId('product_edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Information'));
}
```

with the `setDestElementId` you set the id of the element which will contain the contents while clicking on a tab. Also in this class you can define a `_prepareLayout` method and add the tab to the layout:

```
            $this->addTab('some_name', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('your_helper')->__('tab label'),
                'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('mycomp/myext_mycontrol')->toHtml()),
            ));
```

You can add a tab also from the layout xml by using the `<action method="addTab">`. You can see a couple of examples in `catalog.xml`.
Now that your tab is added, you have to make sure that the container id (what you have specified in the `setDestElementId` method) does exist. So, go back to the `adminhtml_catalog_product_new` layout example, see the reference to the `content`; the block inside should produce the needed id.
When these are all set, your tabs will work.

Comment: I was aiming the layout.xml-less way.  to set the content and left with out the layout file.  by chance do you have a working example?

Comment: Well, I think that is is more complicated without layout xml file. But you can try to play with `$this->getLayout()->getBlock("left")` and with the `createBlock` as it is in the example above to add dynamically the same thing. It will be very ugly in my opinion.